Rust and Sqlx which approach is more resource efficient?
I have Rust Backend and using the Sqlx library I want to insert a single row into a table and then retrieve the latest 10 rows.
Option 1 is to do it all in one query like this:
let new_unit = sqlx::query_as::<_, BaseUnit>(
    "WITH inserted_row AS (
            INSERT INTO product_unit (name)
            VALUES ($1)
            RETURNING id, name
        )
        SELECT * FROM (
            select * from product_unit
            union all
            select * from inserted_row
        ) as combined
        ORDER BY id DESC
        LIMIT 10;",
)

Option 2 is to use two separate queries one executed after the other.
Now which would be considered more resource-efficient?

Check the query plans, using EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS, SETTINGS) for your queries. Most likely option 2 will be the fastest.

What criteria is used to measure resource efficiency: time, memory, IOPs, etc.? It is extremely unlikely that any resource utilization differences between the two approaches will be significant. There are other considerations that are more important than small improvements in efficiency. Simplicity and maintainability are vital concerns. Although the example query is small, it has at least two serious defects: it is invalid when product_unit has more than two columns, and there is no guarantee that inserted_row and product_unit have the same column order.
